# Initial size of a QWidget in a QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a sort of table using QGridLayout and a certain number of Box objects :

Image of the table:
[image]

```
class Mybox(QWidget):
def __init__(self, i, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Mybox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.text = i

def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)

    # Rect info of the box
    rect = event.rect()

    # Draw perimeter of the box
    pen = QPen()
    pen.setWidth(1)
    painter.setPen(pen)
    painter.drawRect(rect)

    # Index of box
    painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 9))
    painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter, str(self.text))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        w = QWidget()

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(0)

        w.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.init_boxes()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.show()

    def init_boxes(self):
        i = 1
        for x in range(2):
            for y in range(2):
                print(i)
                w = Mybox(i)
                self.grid.addWidget(w, x, y)
                i += 1
```

My problem is that I find it impossible to set a initial size of the table based on an initial size of the boxes.

Working with setMinimumSize for the boxes is working for the min size behavior.
But I would like to initialize the table with an intermediate size making it possible to resize down to the min limit or up to the max limit of the MyBox object.

I have tried almost everything (basesize, resize, sizehint etc.) but I guess I am missing something.

I have spent two evening on that and I am clueless...

Bonus question :
The rectangle of my right and lower boxes are not displaying with my code.
I guess it might be a problem of margins but can not figure it out yet.

Comment: You said that you tried using `sizeHint()` (which is the correct method), how?

Comment: Actually I thought about it since I understood that without anything, intial size seems to be the sizeHint value. I did not find a way to change the sizeHint at that time but now that you are saying that this is the way I have found it. Thanks !

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 50)

:)

Comment: About the rectangle rendering question: widgets have integer coordinates, and "integer painting" uses pixels as reference, so what is happening is that the drawn rectangle is actually a pixel too big than the available size: use `drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))`. Also, `event.rect()` is referred to the rectangle in which the painting is requested (which might be only a portion of the widget), so you should use `self.rect()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had to adapt to avoid a 2 pixels line in the middle of table but now everything works as wanted. Very appreciate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, for anyone looking for it in the future.
Thanks to musicamente comment, I have found it :

Reimplement the sizeHint method :

```
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 50)
```